# How to iterate over dataframe using character vector and calculate the mean for matching items in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `character vector` and want to iterate over some `dataframes` and consider the matching characters and note the corresponding values and finally take the average of all the values and store in results in a new `dataframe`.

Below is the sample example:

```
ip <- c("John", "Amanda", "Aaron", "Peter", "Jolie")

dfs <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Peter','jucy'), "value1" = c(21, 24, 26), "value2" = c(20, 23, 32))
dfg <- data.frame("names" = c('Justin','John','Jill'), "value1" = c(35, 11, 10), "value2" = c(10, 28, 27))
dft <- data.frame("names" = c('Louis','Chan','John'), "value1" = c(42, 74, 26), "value2" = c(26, 53, 54))
dfr <- data.frame("names" = c('Ale','Terry','Tom'), "value1" = c(61, 34, 76), "value2" = c(28, 63, 38))
dfm <- data.frame("names" = c('Sam','Jolie','Peter'), "value1" = c(11, 84, 86), "value2" = c(50, 13, 68))
```

Expected output:

```
names  value1  value2
John    19.33  34
Peter   55     45.5
Jolie   84     13
```

For John `value1 = mean(c(21, 11, 26)) = 19.33` and `value2 = mean(c(20, 28, 54)) = 34`

Similarly, for Peter `value1 = mean(c(24, 86)) = 55` and `value2 = mean(c(23,68)) = 45.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `base R` approach would be binding all your dataframes, apply a filter based on `ip` vector and finally aggregate with `mean()`:

```
#Vector
ip <- c("John", "Amanda", "Aaron", "Peter", "Jolie")
#Data
dfs <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Peter','jucy'),
                  "value1" = c(21, 24, 26), "value2" = c(20, 23, 32),stringsAsFactors = F)
dfg <- data.frame("names" = c('Justin','John','Jill'),
                  "value1" = c(35, 11, 10), "value2" = c(10, 28, 27),stringsAsFactors = F)
dft <- data.frame("names" = c('Louis','Chan','John'),
                  "value1" = c(42, 74, 26), "value2" = c(26, 53, 54),stringsAsFactors = F)
dfr <- data.frame("names" = c('Ale','Terry','Tom'),
                  "value1" = c(61, 34, 76), "value2" = c(28, 63, 38),stringsAsFactors = F)
dfm <- data.frame("names" = c('Sam','Jolie','Peter'),
                  "value1" = c(11, 84, 86), "value2" = c(50, 13, 68),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Bind all
dfmacro <- rbind(dfs,dfg,dft,dfr,dfm)
#Filter based on ip
dfmacro2 <- dfmacro[dfmacro$names %in% ip,]
#Aggregate
aggregate(cbind(value1,value2)~names,data=dfmacro2,mean)
```

Output:

```
  names   value1 value2
1  John 19.33333   34.0
2 Jolie 84.00000   13.0
3 Peter 55.00000   45.5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the datasets in a `list` with `mget`, bind them together with `bind_rows`, do a group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mget(ls(pattern= '^df[sgtrms]$')) %>%
    bind_rows %>% 
    group_by(names) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

out
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   names  value1 value2
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Ale      61     28  
# 2 Chan     74     53  
# 3 Jill     10     27  
# 4 John     19.3   34  
# 5 Jolie    84     13  
# 6 jucy     26     32  
# 7 Justin   35     10  
# 8 Louis    42     26  
# 9 Peter    55     45.5
#10 Sam      11     50  
#11 Terry    34     63  
#12 Tom      76     38
```

If we need to `filter` based on `ip`

```
mget(ls(pattern= '^df[sgtrms]$')) %>%
    bind_rows %>% 
    filter(names %in% ip) %>%
    group_by(names) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  names value1 value2
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 John    19.3   34  
#2 Jolie   84     13  
#3 Peter   55     45.5
```

---

Or using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ names, subset(do.call(rbind, 
      mget(ls(pattern = "^df[sgtrms]$"))),  names %in% ip), mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here are two variants which use `data.table`.

The OP has requested to iterate over the dataframes, to extract the desired rows by matching names, and to compute the mean of values for each name across all extracted rows.

All answers posted so far suggest a different order of operations which combines the dataframes first, then extracts the desired rows and aggregates by name, finally.

The two variants suggested in this answer take the same route.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(dfs, dfg, dft, dfr, dfm))[
  names %chin% ip, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = names]
```

> ```
>    names   value1 value2
> 1:  John 19.33333   34.0
> 2: Jolie 84.00000   13.0
> 3: Peter 55.00000   45.5
> ```

`rbindlist()` combines all rows, `names %chin% ip` picks the desired rows, `lapply(.SD, mean)` computes the means across all columns except the `names` column which is used for grouping.

An alternative approach *aggregates in a join*:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(dfs, dfg, dft, dfr, dfm))[
  .(ip), on = .(names = V1), nomatch = NULL, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = .EACHI]
```

Here, the combined rows are joined with `ip`, non matching rows are neglected. Within the join, the data are grouped and aggregated simultaneously.